# Animate to height:auto with newer jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a pair of `<div>` elements set up such that when one `<div>` is clicked, the other animates to the appropriate height for its content.

The script does this by temporarily switching the height to auto, measuring it, and then switching back to the stylesheet height (which is zero).

It works fine but only with jQuery 1.4.4, which is pretty old. Every time I try to put in something that requires a newer version, the animation stops working, either by not animating at all or by both elements disappearing.

I made a JSFiddle below. This version of jQuery wasn't even listed in the libraries so I had to link it externally (under External Resources on the left). If you delete that and set the library to even the lowest available, you'll see what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/27sr4kzv/1/

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){
        var el = $('#ev-donate-form'),
            curHeight = el.height(),
            autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
            el.height(curHeight);
        $("#ev-sponsors").toggle(function(){
            el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 400);
        },function(){
            el.height(autoHeight).animate({height: curHeight}, 400);
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Is there a way I can update this so that I can avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/27sr4kzv/16/

```
$(function(){
  var el = $('#omgivebeenclicked'),
      curHeight = el.height(),
      autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
        el.height(curHeight);


$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {     
    if(el.height() == 0)
        el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 400);
    else
      el.height(autoHeight).animate({height: curHeight}, 400);    
});
});
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The `toggle` function is used to **show/hide** the selected element(s) from the selector, while you are using as `$("#clickme").toggle`, you are just simply showing/hiding the `#clickme` element, read more on http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

which you may want to use is the `.on("click", function () { ...; });` for it (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

The following revised JS achieved the effect:

```
$(function(){
  var el = $('#omgivebeenclicked'),
    IsShown = false,
      curHeight = el.height(),
      autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
        el.height(curHeight);
  $("#clickme").on("click", function(){
    el.height(IsShown ? autoHeight : curHeight).animate({
        height: IsShown ? curHeight : autoHeight
    }, 400);
    IsShown = !IsShown;
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/27sr4kzv/13/

Comment: This one worked great as well, but what does the "IsShown" element do?

Comment: it control the 'state' of the target element, that could prevent any bug caused from multi mouse clicks.